# Colors contour from Python

Tags: python, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I have several hundreds of objects in a scene. I want to distinguish between them using colors contour. The color is interpolated according to the size of the object. Is there any possible way to make this happen from Python?

Comment: Yes, depending on how exactly you define size

Comment: I'll use basically the volume the Bounding Box of the object. If you can help me in this I would be grateful; I have no prior knowledge in rendering in the normal environment (UI) rather than using it in Python.

Comment: Can you post (edit into question)  the code you have so far eg calculating volume from bbox.

Comment: @batFINGER sorry I did not get your question, but for volumes, it's easy to get the size of the bounding box using the following command: 'bpy.data.objects["Name"].dimensions' and this will give u a vector of (x,y,z) dimensions of the BB of any object. If you want to calculate the volumes of complex bodies you can go to the 3D printing addon.